# Difference between is_same and mpl::same_as in boost

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

I cannot seem to see the difference between `boost::is_same` and `boost::mpl::same_as`. Could someone perhaps point these out and where only the specific variant can be used.

Comment: It could be that `boost::is_same` is there for compatibility with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), while `boost::mpl::same_as` is an older variant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, nothing. If you actually look at the [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/mpl/same_as.hpp) of `mpl::same_as`, it includes `is_same` and then uses it directly.

Note that `<type_traits>` is part of the standard library as of C++11, and includes `std::is_same` (which acts exactly like the aforementioned two functions in boost).

Comment: While the check performed is the same, `same_as`'s interface seems to be different.